# Cálculos en campos DEFAULT en MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

Hola y muchas gracias de antemano por su ayuda,

Estoy intentando algo que estoy seguro que debería de ser fácil, pero después de buscar durante algunos días, he decidido preguntar a esta comunidad. Aunque con algo de experiencia en programación, soy novato a lo que bases de datos se refiere...

Estoy usando **MariaDB 10.3.21**, y tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
  CREATE TABLE `Inventory` (
  `InventoryId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'InternalIdentifier',
  `ProductId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Related Product Identifier',
  `DeviceSN` varchar(40) DEFAULT concat(year(current_timestamp()),month(current_timestamp()),dayofmonth(current_timestamp())),
  `ExternalManufactured` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 1 COMMENT 'if =1 No Needs generate My own serial Number',
  PRIMARY KEY (`InventoryId`),
  KEY `Inventory_FK` (`ProductId`),
  CONSTRAINT `Inventory_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`ProductId`) REFERENCES `Products` (`ProductId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Device Inventory table'
```

Me gustaría insertar un valor automático para `DeviceSN`. Este valor es la fecha actual y un contador. Este contador seria la cantidad de equipos NO fabricados externamente (*es decir, la cantidad de columnas donde `ExternalManufactured=0`*)

Puedo crear una tabla auxiliar con este contador, que se agrega mediante un trigger cuando hay datos insertados en la tabla `Inventory`. Lo que no sé es cómo concatenar este valor (contador) a la fecha actual y que sea el valor por defecto en `DeviceSN`.

He probado con triggers, y con *generated columns*, pero no se como añadir este contador para poderlo concatenar con la fecha actual...

De hecho, con un contador aunque no se cumpla la condición de `ExternalManufactured=0` ya seria suficiente, pero he probado con una columna auto-increment:

```
ALTER TABLE DeviceManagement.Inventory MODIFY COLUMN DeviceSN varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT concat(year(current_timestamp()),month(current_timestamp()),dayofmonth(current_timestamp()),CAST(InventoryId AS CHAR)) NULL;
```

Y me aparece el error:

> Function or expression 'AUTO_INCREMENT' cannot be used in the DEFAULT clause of `InventoryId

Cualquier consejo será bienvenido...

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Cuando creas la tabla puedes usar:                                                              
    CREATE TABLE birthday(name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,date DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
time TIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME
);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No recuerdo haber visto documentación o ejemplo de valores por defecto personalizados. Al menos no con las subqueries que utilizas.

Sin embargo, una opción que puedes tomar es **utilizar un trigger**. Estos disparadores se ejecutan cuando se realiza cierta operación sobre la tabla.

En tu caso, al parecer es al insertar en ella, entonces tu trigger podría tener la opción de `BEFORE INSERT` (antes de insertar), y, en este, modificar el valor a insertar:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_devicesn BEFORE INSERT ON Inventory
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.DeviceSN = (concat(year(current_timestamp()),
                              month(current_timestamp()),
                              dayofmonth(current_timestamp())));
END;
```

Después de que guardes este trigger, puedes insertar valores en la tabla de la siguiente manera:

```
INSERT INTO Inventory (ProductId, DeviceSN, ExternalManufactured)
VALUES (1,NULL,1);
```

Es decir, con los valores `<numero>, NULL, <numero>`. Entonces, dentro de la tabla `Inventory`, podrás ver columnas de la forma:

```
> SELECT * FROM Inventory;
InventoryId  ProductId  DeviceSN  ExternalManufactured
23           1          20201116  1
24           2          20201116  2
```

Comment: Solucionado, Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Cuando creas la tabla puedes usar CURRENT_DATE y CURRENT_TIME:

```
CREATE TABLE birthday(
name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
date DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
time TIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME
);
```

Y para el campo que tiene los equipos no fabricados externamente usuaría otro campo el cual rellenaría realizando previamente una consulta SELECT para saber cuantos hay.

Así cuando insertes o modifiques un nuevo registro te aseguras que está todo actualizado y me olvidaría de triggers y tablas adicionales.

Saludos

Comment: Gracias @juan. Añadir la fecha/hora al actualizar la tabla no hay problema. Lo que necesitaría es que DeviceSN tenga el formato DDMMAAA+Counter. Ya añado bien CONCAT(year(now().... ) pero me falta como añadir un contador.
Cómo relleno un campo a través de una consulta Select? la expresión de un campo en una generated column puede contener un Select?

Comment: Primero se hace un SELECT count(*) donde guardas en una variable el valor del total de los equipos no fabricados externamente llamada Counter. Luego usas esa variable en la clausula UPDATE concretamente en el CONCAT.

Comment: Hay muchas formas de hacer las cosas obviamente. Yo te recomiendo que cuanto más sencillas de hacer y comprender mejor. Slds,

Comment: El concat sería algo así... CONCAT(year(now(), Counter)   separas con comas los campos a concatenar. Mírate la documentación.https://mariadb.com/kb/en/concat/  Y lo que yo usaría es una sentencia UPDATE con una variable. No se puede hacer un UPDATE con un SELECT dentro del SET de una variable. Hay que usar variables/expresiones que corresponden por ejemplo al resultado de un SELECT anterior. Saludos.

Comment: Otra forma de hacerlo es especificar otro campo más al crear la tabla 'Counter int(8) not null auto_increment' y te evitas problemas por que realmente tanto te da tener 1 campo con todo que 2 con la fecha y el Counter.